# How to apply html head to multiple pages?

Tags: php, html, head

I'm using PHP into HTML body to place header and footer, is there any way to applying head element into multiple pages just like `wp_head()`?

Comment: `include()` or `require()` or `require_once()`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a HTML file for Header and using **PHP** you can use:

```
<?php require_once('header.php'); >
```

or

```
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```